# When to use 되다 vs 돼다?

Tags: word-choice

I often find myself pausing before deciding whether I should be using `되다` or `돼다` in a sentence.

Is there a simple rule to know when I should be using which?

Comment: 돼 is the contraction of 되어.

Comment: You never use 돼다.

Comment: 돼 is the contraction of 되어, right. One of the famous ways for natives to know when to use 되 and 돼 is that, you put 하 or 해 first, whichever sounds right, and replace it with 되 or 돼 respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'-되' + '-어, -어라, 어서, 어야, -었-' 
= 되어, 되어라, 되어서, 되어야, 되었다 
=> 돼, 돼서, 돼야, 됐다

되다 (o) 
돼다 (x)

'-되' is a stem so it cannot be used alone.

돼 (o)
되 (x)

되니 (o)
돼니 (x)

안돼 (o)
안되 (x)

Comment: Thanks for the examples!